# Why does RedisTemplate with jedis execute "select" command for every operation when database index is different 0

Tags: spring-data-redis

Recently, I use RedisTemplate with jedis connection factory in my project to get values from redis. I find out that RedisTemplate will execute "select" command before and after operation when the database index is different from 0.

The demo code I use is very basic

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        String value = redisTemplate.opsForValue().get("hello");
        System.out.println(value);
    }
```

The sample output from redis monitor is

```
1512198566.756217 [0 192.168.33.1:59691] "SELECT" "4"
1512198566.757251 [4 192.168.33.1:59691] "GET" "hello"
1512198566.758367 [4 192.168.33.1:59691] "SELECT" "0"
1512198566.761262 [0 192.168.33.1:59691] "SELECT" "4"
1512198566.763201 [4 192.168.33.1:59691] "GET" "hello"
1512198566.764959 [4 192.168.33.1:59691] "SELECT" "0"
```

However JedisPool doesn't have similar process

```
1512198527.317110 [0 192.168.33.1:59676] "SELECT" "4"
1512198527.325005 [4 192.168.33.1:59676] "GET" "hello"
1512198527.334189 [4 192.168.33.1:59676] "GET" "hello"
```

What's the benefit that RedisTemplate execute extra "select", and will the frequent "select" command reduce the client performance?